# About terminate condition of for-loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

Why can't I use this?

```
for(int i=0; i<haystack.length()-needle.length()+1; i++)
```

I got error when haystack="abb" needle="abaaa".

It has no error if I use:

```
int diff=haystack.length()-needle.length()+1;
for(int i=0; i<diff; i++)
```

This is the function:

```
int strStr(string haystack, string needle){
        if(needle.length()==0)
            return 0;
        if(haystack.length()==0)// || haystack.length() < needle.length())
            return -1;

        int diff=haystack.length()-needle.length()+1;
      for(int i=0; i<(haystack.length()-needle.length()+1); i++){
      //for(int i=0; i<diff; i++){
//          printf("%d %d\n",haystack.length(),needle.length());
        for(int j=0; j<needle.length(); j++){
          if(haystack.at(i+j)!=needle.at(j))
            break;

          if(j==needle.length()-1)
            return i;
        }
      }

      return -1;
    }
```

Comment: `std::string.length()` returns a value of type `size_t`, which is unsigned. The substraction then results in a unsigned integer overflow

Comment: @IGarFieldl Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing problems due to the way you are applying arithmetic to unsigned `length()` values. Change:

```
for(int i=0; i<haystack.length()-needle.length()+1; i++)
```

to:

```
for(size_t i=0; i+needle.length()<=haystack.length(); i++)
```

This keeps both the left and right side of the comparison positive, avoiding the negative underflow in your original example.